# Buffer toString include all letters of alphabet

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, random, cryptography

I'm using Node.js to create secure, random tokens. Take this example:

```
crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex");
// dd89d6ab1a7196e8797c2da0da0208a5d171465a9d8e918d3b138f08af3e1852
```

That's great, but it's a lot longer than it needs to be. I want to include all letters of the alphabet, not just `a`-`f`. Even better if it also includes capital letters. Remember, it needs to be *secure*, so it can't use `Math.random`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('base64');
```

Comment: Upvoted, but base64 strings include non-alphanumerical characters

Comment: It generates alphanumeric value like: Pvvyt1lSqiPUPH5oUfMQYyHaDCUp0uIwbbpPJ4uesZo=

Comment: It can also generate values like `dxNdBHzLGm4DUMMFkTh81R+ihzab5Jw+QYH7PBekjRg=`, which contains the non-alphanumeric values `+` and `=`.

Comment: You can replace them.

Comment: True, so I'm leaving the upvote. But I think a better answer is possible.

Comment: Still you can try this: crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('base64').replace(/[^a-z0-9]|\s+|\r?\n|\r/gmi, "")

Comment: @iONinja you might wanna look at base58. you'll need an npm module to use it in node js https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs58

Comment: @YoniJah Oh my gosh yes! That's so clever, not having "l" so as not to confuse with "1", and "0" to confuse with "O". That's the optimal alphabet to use! :O

Answer (score 1):

Generate a suitably sized random number.  Convert it to base 36 (for 0..9, a..z) or base 62 (for 0..9, a..z, A..Z).

Comment: How do I generate a random number *securely*?

Comment: In Java use `java.security.SecureRandom()`.  Many other languages will have a similar method in their libraries somewhere.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an exact equivalent in JavaScript, but it could be done in a non-ideal way.

Comment: I am afraid I do not know enough JavaScript to say.  One possibility is to access the Windows secure RNG function directly: CryptAPI CryptGenRandom.  I presume that Apple systems have an equivalent.  Alternatively look for a JavaScript implementation of Yarrow or Fortuna crypto RNGs.